# FadeIn appended div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I load some divs with append. Works, but I'd like to fade it in. Fade Out works but not fade in...

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay1">'),
    overlayBox  = $('<div id="overlay2">');
    $('body').append(overlay1, overlay2).fadeIn(500);                   
});
```

Comment: Make sure to close those <div> tags.

Comment: Do you mean $('<div id="overlay1"></div>')

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    var overlay = $('<div id="overlay1">Test 1</div>'),
    overlayBox  = $('<div id="overlay2">Test 2</div>');
    $('body').append(overlay, overlayBox);
    overlay.hide().fadeIn(500);
    overlayBox.hide().fadeIn(500);    
});
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ycb5/**

Also, just so you know - `.append()` is chainable, so doing `$('body').append(overlay, overlayBox).fadeIn()` wouldn't fade in the `overlay` and `overlayBox` but fade in the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you are adding fully opaque divs, and then trying to fade them in (which doesn't work. What are they fading from?) If you added the divs with Opacity = 0, then your code would work.